# Removing SVG from dom and memory

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, memory-leaks, svg

I'm doing some music visualisation experiment and it draws data from dancer.js on canvas or svg, depending on chosen visualisation. I have 4 options: clear js on canvas, raphaeljs on both svg, and three.js in the last one.

To keep the sound element and prevent reloading dancer.js i load different scripts in the following manner:

```
            $('body > a').click(function(){
                $('canvas').remove();
                $('svg').empty();
                $('svg').remove();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                audioElement = $('#audio')[0];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "js/"+id+"-ajax.js",
                    dataType: "script"
                });
            });
```

it should just remove the canvas and svg if there are any and different visualisation are caught by ajax in which there is

```
  init = function() {
    ...
  }
  init();
```

they share the same functions like `onKick` which is changed in the init respectivly to the loaded script. (onKick is for dancer.js to fire it upon a "kick" in the song being played).

it works quite good till the moment you start switching between them. switching between canvas and canvas makes almost no difference, but when i change from canvas to svg, and than back to canvas framarate drops drastically.

May it be because of the svg being held in the memory or some other suggestions?

Comment: watch carefully the DOM (if clears properly) and use chrome for timeline and profiling to see the peaks, tell us how many SVG elements the scripts create ? 10-100-1000 ? My sugestion is to move 100% to canvas, SVG is limited, and so last century.

Comment: @B3aT it creates ~ 100 paths (creating triangles) - i use it because raphaeljs has very nice animations, which i wasnt able to recreate on canvas.